# Setup mapnik: tile generation very slow

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, tile-server

I've setup a Mapnik tileserver with this steps: https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/

This are the specs of my server:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- 8 vcpu's
- 28 GB RAM

I've imported an extract of Europe (Belgium-Netherlands-France-Germany). Tile server is running, but tile generation is very slow. When showing tiles in a leaflet map, it can take 30-40 seconds to render one mapview. I've followed the steps from https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/ literally.

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: do you have a tile cache in place on the server (e.g. [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/))? I don't know much about Mapnik but without a tile cache, it sounds like it might be (re-)rendering all tiles on demand. MapProxy will cache rendered tiles and send those back to clients, which should be much faster. You can also 'seed the cache' (e.g. pre-render all tiles up to zoom level 10, or higher zoom levels in particular areas)

Comment: I can't comment from experience about how fast that spec of server should render a tile based on most of western Europe, but I doubt that 30-40s is excessive for low zoom tiles.  Normally people pre-render low zoom tiles so that there's always a tile available, even if it's not bang up to date.  Try giving timings for a /dirty on tiles at different zoom levels, e.g. https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/7/65/43.png and https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/17/67021/44876.png (but obviously on your system, not osm.org).

Comment: @Steven Kay Renderd/Mod_tile (which those instructions use) can render on demand but will return an existing tile out to the requester if one exists.  On a public site I prerender up to z12 using render_list, and that replaces tiles that are 4 days old.

Comment: One more thing - if you look at /var/log/syslog you'll see "START TILE" and "DONE TILE" and more besides as it's actually rendering tiles.

Comment: Get better processing power,vCPUs wont cut it in this arena. I have 24 cores and this `screen render_list -m default -a -z 15 -Z 19 --num-threads=22` is taking ages. Get a dedicated server, AWS "vCPU" is.... poor at his particular task.

Answer (score 1):

A key factor in tile rendering is the server configuration. For an example, here is the configuration of the OSM tiles generation server: https://hardware.openstreetmap.org/servers/odin.openstreetmap.org/

Disk access is important, on a cloud based server the disk access may slow tile rendering.